# convert string hours:minutes:sec.milisec to seconds

Tags: string, parsing, wolfram-mathematica

An absolute time is given in stored in this format:

```
time = "000:03:07.447"
```

How can this string be converted to seconds in an elegant way?

Update:

As suggested by Harper89

```
3600*#1 + 60*#2 + #3 & @@ ToExpression[StringSplit["000:00:04.424", ":"]]
```

Szabolcs suggested to use AbsoluteTime
From Mathematica help: AbsoluteTime gives the total number of seconds since the beginning of January 1, 1900, in your time zone.

```
AbsoluteTime[{"000:03:07.447", {"Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second", 
".", "Millisecond"}}] 
-  AbsoluteTime[{"000:00:00.000", {"Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second",
 ".", "Millisecond"}}]
```

This works both

Comment: It seems `AbsoluteTime` has changed between versions 7 and 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as harper89 described, in *Mathematica*:

```
FromDigits[ToExpression /@ StringSplit[time, ":"], 60]
```

Answer (score 4):

Parse the string to form an array between each of the : using something like `split()`

1. For the first set multiply by the number of seconds in an hour
2. For the second set multiply by the number of seconds in a minute
3. For the third set add the number to the total

In other words

```
totalseconds = array(0)*3600 + array(1)*60 + array(2)
```

Or in vb.net Code

```
  Dim time As String = "000:3:7"        
  Dim a() As String  
  a = longstring.Split(":")
  Dim TotalSeconds as Integer = (a(0) * 86400) + (a(1) * 3600) + a(2))
  Trace.WriteLine(TotalSeconds.toString)
```

From the Tag definition of mathmatica

> Not to be confused with mathematics (math).

OOPs..

Comment: @Szabolcs you cannot blame him; one may assume that all *Mathematica* questions will be posted [where they belong](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) :-)

Comment: Ahh, I read it as he was looking for techniques that could be used. He edited and I understand exactly what he means now. My fault. (But hey now he knows to split!)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
AbsoluteTime[{"000:03:07.447", 
      {"Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", "Millisecond"}}]

(* ==> 187.447 *)
```

The key was giving an explicit date format (see the docs of `DateList[]`)

This solution works in Mathematica 8.  It appears that in version 7 (and possibly also in version 6) one needs to correct the result, like this:

```
AbsoluteTime[{"000:03:07.447", 
      {"Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", "Millisecond"}}] -
AbsoluteTime[{"0", {"Hour"}}]
```

Comment: I don't think he wants the *Mathematica* epoch for this, but his own.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My code converts it to seconds correctly, just try it.  I am aware that Mathematica considers 1900 january 1 as start of all time, but this is not an issue here.

Comment: This returns `3.534364987447000000000000*10^9` -- I think he simply wants `187.447`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I get `187.447`.  Did we come across a version difference again?  Let's go to chat